# Only 1 arrow flashing when connected to wi-fi

Tags: wi-fi

Recently when I connect to my companies  wi-fi network, it  says I'm connected with 1 bar the up arrow flashes white but the down arrow does not flash at all and I can not use any apps internet, nothing! (I never had this problem before)

Can someone please help. I have reset my phone, turned it off and on 100 times , clicked forget network and retyped in password etc.. says I'm connected to network but no internet?

I use Samsung galaxy note 2

Comment: Is anyone else facing this issue or only you? It probably is a firewall that is preventing you from connecting to the internet.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your work Wi-Fi network. You should ask the IT support helpdesk.

Answer (score -1):

Here's your solution to the *only one arrow of wi-fi is blinking issue*

- long press your wi-fi network, an option will appear 'modify network' click this.
- Go to advanced setting and change your Ipv4 address from 'static' to 'DHCP'.
- After this also if your problem is not solved then contact to wi-fi owner.

Answer (score -3):

your firewall is preventing your phone to access or connect to the internet.check your firewall settings. or may be this happen due to some problem in your router.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's great that you're trying to help, but I wonder how much use a suggestion to "check your firewall settings" is. If the questioner didn't already realise that, they probably need more specific advice about what settings to check.